# Custom formatted string as JSON value. Yay or nay?

Tags: json, parsing

I want to send JSON structured something like this

```
{
    "buttons": {
        "track": {
            "type": 0,
            "visibility": 1,
            "visibility_text": "I am visible"
        },
        "call": {
            "type": 0,
            "visibility": 1,
            "visibility_text": "I am visible"
        }
        // 12 or so more children of button node
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a lot of duplication going on here. I am thinking of sending sending a token separated string rather repeating the type, visibility and visibility_text nodes. Something like this

```
{
    "buttons": {
        "track": "0|1|I am visible",
        "call": "0|1|I am visible"
    }
}
```

The amount of data to be transferred is greatly reduced, but at the cost of readability, which is not a high concern since this is a private API.

What are the pros and cons of the second approach? Any other suggestions are welcome too.

Comment: You can use arrays which are easier to parse. `"call": [0, 1, "I am visible"]`

Answer (score 4):

> What are the pros and cons of the second approach?

Cons

- unreadable
- order of parameters is crucial
- requires manual parsing
- cannot use the delimiter `|` in string literals

Pros

- None. It's 2016, a couple of extra lines in a payload doesn't increase the performance.

Go for readability. The api is private now, but in the future it may not be. Or it may have to be maintained by someone other than you.

Go for ease of parsing. Having to implement custom json parsing introduces code that was not necessary. Having to take into account in which order the parameters are is not something you want to do. If they are accidentally are mixed up, everything breaks.